# Is it possible to depict the bitcoin mining problem as a TSP-metric problem?

Tags: cryptocurrency, hardness-assumptions

I wonder if someone can represent the blockchain encryption problem (used to mine bitcoins) as a TSP-metric problem (where TSP = Traveling-Salesman Problem). Any approach or intuition of the idea to do that is welcome.

Comment: Maybe it is just me missing knowledge, but can you provide a pointer to "the blockchain encryption problem"? And how is that used to *mine* bitcoins?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'd _suppose_ that the "blockchain encryption problem" is bitcoin's mining problem (ie finding a nonce such that the hash of the nonce with some data is smaller than some threshold).

Comment: In theory this is "easy": TSP is NP-hard, so you can map any NP-problem to it which includes bitcoin mining.

Comment: @SEJPM TSP-metric (euclidean) is NP-complete as Papadimitrious  (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christos_Papadimitriou) showed in the 80´s. Anyway .. do you know how to implement a TSP for mining bitcoins?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. To think that it would be possible is surely to make a category error.  Mining Bitcoin is not an issue of finding the shortest possible route between successful mining events, nor, by the way, is it encryption (strictly speaking).

There is a common feature, of course, between the TSP and Bitcoin mining: the need to save time. But a time solution to a TSP problem is very different from one in Bitcoin mining because the TSP looks to find the shortest route of all, and we have to prove that it is absolutely the shortest. This is nothing like  mining Bitcoin.

Comment: could you explain graphically the difference? If you can add a link to an extended explanation it would be great. THX

Comment: How does "the need to save time" manifest itself in the Bitcoin mining problem?

Comment: @dionyziz   time = money

Comment: @Patriot I´m not sure at all about that ... the PoW is not simply a lottery, it is a sequence of the previous known transactions of the block. You can calculate this if you can decipher the previous.